# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"_glutInit", referenced from:_main in main.o / Netbeans on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, netbeans, glut

My program is this Sierpinski Gasket.  I'm using Netbeans on my MacBook Pro and I believe I have the libraries installed but maybe they are not linked correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <OpenGL/glext.h>

void myinit(){
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,50.0,0.0,50.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void display(){
    GLfloat vertices[3][2]={{0.0,0.0},{25.0,50.0},{50.0,0.0}};
    int i, j, k;
    int rand();
    GLfloat p[2]={7.5,5.0};
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);

    for(k=0; k<5000; k++){
        j=rand()*3;
        p[0]=(p[0]+vertices[j][0])/2.0;
        p[1]=(p[1]+vertices[j][1])/2.0;
        glVertex2fv(p);
    }

    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutCreateWindow("Sierpinski Gasket");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    myinit();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Here are the compilation errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glutInit", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glutInitDisplayMode", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glutInitWindowSize", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glutInitWindowPosition", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glutCreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glutDisplayFunc", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glutMainLoop", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/sierpinski] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Answer (score 16):

You need to link the GLUT framework. In Project Properties > Linker > Command Line > Aditional Options, specify

```
-framework GLUT
```

Comment: And for similar error with OpenGL functions add also -framework OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

Slight correction in your code:

```
j = rand() % 3;
```

and not `rand() * 3;`. That gives seg fault for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

To complement @user55721's GLUT framework answer, in the context of installing JasPer.

The INSTALL doc mentions an arch specific `cmake` option to use **native** GLUT on Mac OS:

> When building the JasPer software under Mac OSX, only the use of the
> native framework for OpenGL is officially supported.  If the Freeglut
> library is installed on your system, you will need to ensure that the
> native GLUT library (as opposed to the Freeglut library) is used by
> the build process.  This can be accomplished by adding an extra option
> to the cmake command line that resembles the following:
>
> ```
> -DGLUT_glut_LIBRARY=/System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework
> ```